# Is this relative clause correct? " There are three people like eating bread."

Tags: relative-clauses

Is this sentence correct?  I bet we need "who" in the middle.

> There are three people like eating bread.

Comment: Deletion of _who_ (or _that_) here is probably an accepted conversational deletion in the States. But I'd hazard _non-standard_.

Comment: In the context of a novel it could work.  In the context of an English test it wouldn't.

Comment: I would avoid anyone you hear speaking like that!